# Sort an increasing array

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

The pseudo codes:

```
S = {};
Loop 10000 times:
    u = unsorted_fixed_size_array_producer();
    S = sort(S + u);
```

I need an efficient implementation of sort, which takes a sorted array and an unsorted one, then sort them all. But here we know after a few iterations, *size(S)* will be much bigger than *size(u)*, that's a prior.

Update: There's another prior: the size of *u* is known, say 10 or 20, and the looping times is also known.

**Update:** I implemented the algorithm that @Dukelnig advised in C https://gist.github.com/blackball/bd7e5619a1e83bd985a3 which fits for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: How important is it for `S` to be an *array* specifically? Can you keep it as a tree or a list and then *convert* it to an array when all is done?

Comment: ^^^ Yes, better to just maintain a sorted collection than to sort an array a ton of times

Comment: I wonder if Professors search this site for cheaters! ;-)

Comment: What is your criteria for 'efficient'? Do you have any more information on the constraints? Does the S need to be queried at all before this loop has completed?

Comment: @AndreyT In fact, after every *sort*, I will use S for other purpose. So I think S need to be an array here.

Comment: @bdean20 Less time, and less space. And S need to be queried after every *sort*.

Comment: What types of queries do you have? Do you know how many queries there are between insertions?

Comment: If somebody's answer helped you, accepting that answer is a much clearer way of signaling that your question has been solved than adding a note to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Sort `u`, then merge `S` and `u`.

Merging simply involves iterating through two sorted arrays at the same time, and picking the smaller element and incrementing that iterator at each step.

The running time is `O(|u| log |u| + |S|)`.

This is very similar to what [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) does, so that it would result in a sorted array can be derived from there.

Some Java code for merge, derived from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort): (the C code wouldn't look all that different)

```
static void merge(int S[], int u[], int newS[])
{
   int iS = 0, iu = 0;

   for (int j = 0; j < S.length + u.length; j++)
      if (iS < S.length && (iu >= u.length || S[iS] <= u[iu]))
         newS[j] = S[iS++];  // Increment iS after using it as an index
      else
         newS[j] = u[iu++];  // Increment iu after using it as an index
}
```

This can also be done in-place (in S, assuming it has enough additional space) by going from the back.
Here's some working Java code that does this:

```
static void mergeInPlace(int S[], int SLength, int u[])
{
   int iS = SLength-1, iu = u.length-1;

   for (int j = SLength + u.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
      if (iS >= 0 && (iu < 0 || S[iS] >= u[iu]))
         S[j] = S[iS--];
      else
         S[j] = u[iu--];
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int[] S = {1,5,9,13,22, 0,0,0,0}; // 4 additional spots reserved here
   int[] u = {0,10,11,15};
   mergeInPlace(S, 5, u);
   // prints [0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 22]
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(S));
}
```

To reduce the number of comparisons, we can also use binary search (although the time complexity would remain the same - this can be useful when comparisons are expensive).

```
// returns the first element in S before SLength greater than value,
//   or returns SLength if no such element exists
static int binarySearch(int S[], int SLength, int value) { ... }

static void mergeInPlaceBinarySearch(int S[], int SLength, int u[])
{
   int iS = SLength-1;
   int iNew = SLength + u.length - 1;

   for (int iu = u.length-1; iu >= 0; iu--)
   {
      if (iS >= 0)
      {
         int index = binarySearch(S, iS+1, u[iu]);
         for ( ; iS >= index; iS--)
            S[iNew--] = S[iS];
      }
      S[iNew--] = u[iu];
   }
   // assert (iS != iNew)
   for ( ; iS >= 0; iS--)
      S[iNew--] = S[iS];
}
```

**If `S` doesn't have to be an array**

The above assumes that `S` has to be an array. If it doesn't, something like a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) might be better, depending on how large `u` and `S` are.

The running time would be `O(|u| log |S|)` - just substitute some values to see which is better.

Comment: If we finish adding from sorted 'u' during the merge with S. Wouldn't adding the rest from 'S' result in an unsorted final array? I may have misunderstand...

Comment: In other words, this is insertion sort from a pre-sorted `u` with each next search in `S` starting from the point of the last insertion. However, the insertion time will be dominated by the array element relocation time in `S`, which means that for large `S`  and small `u` it won't matter much whether `u` is sorted or not. A plain insertion from an unsorted `u` will work just as well (or just as poorly).

Comment: @namar0x0309 Because of the way the merge is done, this would result in a sorted array. [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) depends on that it gives a sorted array and the correctness can be derived from that.

Comment: @AndreyT Element-by-element insertion of u into S is `O(|u||S|)`, merging is `O(|u| + |S|)`, huge difference.

Comment: @Dukeling: I don't know where you got your `O(|u||S|)`. This just doesn't make sense. The search for each insertion point in `S` should be done by *binary search*, not by linear search. That gives us `O(|u| log|S|)` complexity for searches, which is much better than your `O(|u| + |S|)` when `|u|` is small compared to `|S|`. That's actually how the classic array merge algorithm is implemented when arrays sizes are significantly different: through binary search instead of linear one. Your `O(|u| + |S|)` approach is only usable when array sizes are close to each other. In this case they are not.

Comment: @AndreyT The problem is the shifting that needs to happen, not to just find the correct position - if you insert an element at the beginning, you need to literally shift the entire S up to make room for it (which takes `O(|S|)`), and since there are `|u|` inserts, this would take `O(|u||S|)`.

Comment: @Dukeling: OK, I got what you mean. I thought you were talking about *comparison* complexity only. What I mean is that out-of-place array-merge algorithm and in-place insertion sort algorithm is basically two varieties (in-place and out-of-place) of the same algorithm. I don't insist in in-place version, since indeed it will make insertions too costly. Now, out-of-place algorithm with linear search with require `O(|S|+|u|)` comparisons and `O(|S|+|u|)` copyings. The same algorithm with binary search will require `O(|u| log|S|)` comparisons and the same `O(|S|+|u|)` copyings.

Comment: The only points I'm trying to make is that 1) the latter is much better (in terms of number of comparisons), when `|u|` is much smaller than `|S|`, 2) the latter does not really care much whether `u` is sorted or not, when `|u|` is much smaller than `|S|`.

Comment: @AndreyT Yes, merging with binary search will reduce the number of comparisons. What is "the latter" you're talking about here? If it's insertion sort, fair enough. If it's merge with binary search, it will still require sorting `u` first as you need to know how much room to leave where for the elements of `u`.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes, you are right. An out-of-place array merge implementation will certainly require *both* arrays be sorted. A total brain glitch on my part. Sorry for the unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Dukeling Hi I implemented the algorithm above in C, I've added the link in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really really have to use a literal *array* for `S` at all times, then the best approach would be to individually insert the new elements into the already sorted `S`. I.e. basically use the classic insertion sort technique for each element in each new batch. This will be expensive in a sense that insertion into an array is expensive (you have to move the elements), but that's the price of having to use an array for `S`.

Answer (score 0):

So if the size of S is much more than the size of u, isn't what you want simply an efficient sort for a mostly sorted array? Traditionally this would be insertion sort. But you will only know the real answer by experimentation and measurement - try different algorithms and pick the best one. Without actually running your code (and perhaps more importantly, with your data), you cannot reliably predict performance, even with something as well studied as sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a big sorted list of size `n` and a little sorted list of size `k`.

Binary search, starting from the end (position `n-1`, `n-2`, `n-4`, &c) for the insertion point for the largest element of the smaller list. Shift the tail end of the larger list `k` elements to the right, insert the largest element of the smaller list, then repeat.

So if we have the lists `[1,2,4,5,6,8,9]` and `[3,7]`, we will do:

```
[1,2,4,5,6, , ,8,9]
[1,2,4,5,6, ,7,8,9]
[1,2, ,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But I would advise you to benchmark just concatenating the lists and sorting the whole thing before resorting to interesting merge procedures.